# LINQ with joins and a List<GUID>

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

Here's the SQL that I used to prototype the LINQ statement.  The GUID's in code are `List<GUID>`.  I tried for 3 hours and just don't get it.  Could some kind sole who can write LINQ in their sleep help me out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  [id]
      ,[emailAddress]
      ,[name]
      ,[emailRunNumber]
  FROM [emailAddress]
  join promotionsJoin
  on promotionsJoin.EmailAddressId = emailAddress.id
  where promotionsJoin.promotionId in ('09464b57-f3d7-41ec-b0b1-cbc5999824bd',
  '8bc855b2-2f01-4083-b43a-dab7b7a81ac8') AND emailRunNumber is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(from emailAddress in emailAddresses
 join promotion in promotions 
   on emailAddress.id equals promotion.EmailAddressId
 where guidsList.Contains(promotion.promotionId)
    && promotion.emailRunNumber == null
 select new {
     emailAddress.id,
     emailAddress.emailAddress,
     promotion.name,
     promotion.emailRunNumber
}).Distinct()
```

The join here will be unnecessary if there's already a relationship between the two tables in your mapping (then `promotion` will just be a field off of `emailAddress`)

Comment: This seems close... promotion doesn't have emailAddressId but there is the PromotionJoin as Klaus points out.  (Today is a holiday... I'll work this out tomorrow in LINQPad tomorrow and post my findings)  Thanks bdukes!

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator is not supported by linq-to-entities, but you could do it like this.

```
var result = YourObjectContext.EmailAddress
                .Where(ea => ea.emailRunNumber == null 
                && (ea.PromotionJoin.promotionId == new Guid("09464b57-f3d7-41ec-b0b1-cbc5999824bd") || 
                    ea.PromotionJoin.promotionId == new Guid("8bc855b2-2f01-4083-b43a-dab7b7a81ac8"));
```

The EF generated class called `EmailAddress` will automatically have a field called `PromotionJoin` provided that your `PromotionJoin` table has a foreign key reference to the primary key of `EmailAddress`.

Comment: @abatischev, oops, forgot to change that when copying from question.

Comment: Klaus, sorry I wasn't clear in my original post.. I have a List<Guid> in code, but prototyped it in SQL, however I think the clue of using the PromotionJoin will help me.
(Today is a holiday I'll work this out tomorrow in LINQPad tomorrow and post my findings)

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Klaus' answer:

```
var result = YourObjectContext.EmailAddress
    .Where(ea =>
        ea.emailRunNumber == null &&
        new[]
        {
            new Guid("09464b57-f3d7-41ec-b0b1-cbc5999824bd"),
            new Guid("8bc855b2-2f01-4083-b43a-dab7b7a81ac8"
        }.Contains(ea.PromotionJoin.promotionId))
    .Distinct();
```

or

```
var result = YourObjectContext.EmailAddress
    .Where(ea =>
        ea.emailRunNumber == null &&
        new[]
        {
            "09464b57-f3d7-41ec-b0b1-cbc5999824bd",
            "8bc855b2-2f01-4083-b43a-dab7b7a81ac8"
        }.Select(s => new Guid(s)).Contains(ea.PromotionJoin.promotionId));
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I'm beginning to see why LINQ can be a bit of a challenge to learn... there are so many ways to get the job done.  As I mention above in response to Klaus, I apologize for not being clear.  I have a List<GUID> however today is a holiday so I'll work this out tomorrow with the help you kind folks have provided and post my findings.
Thanks, Abatishchev!

Comment: @George: Glad to help! Describe your question more and I'll try to assist you :)